# RGB values from image into a one dimension array in c#

Tags: c#, image, pixel

I was wondering if there is a was a way to read rgb values from an image into a one dimensional array in C#. If it doesnt make sense, in java I would do something like this.

```
int[] pixels;
BufferedImage image = getClass().getResourceAsStream("asdfghjkl.png");

int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();

pixels = new int[w * h];
image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w) ;
```

So any help would be great, or if you can point me in the right direction, that'd be great

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127871/how-can-i-read-image-pixels-values-as-rgb-into-2d-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Memory, 2d Arrays are still linear 1d arrays. they are just stored after each other, so accesing a position at XY would be the following : 
pixel = width * y + x;

And reading images in C# is wery much possible. it would be just to read a file with a streamreader, and then you have to take account with the header describing the images. from there you can easily read pixels. Bare in mind that PNG is a pretty HARD format to read, and there are helpers all around the internet if you google some.

Reading a TGA is much easier where the structure is just like the following : 
Header ( about 32b ) 
Pixels

This site tells you how to read a text file, the principle is the same, you just have to know the structure of the image type. [Loading an textfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

this site also explains the layout for a .tga file : [TGA structure](http://www.paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/) 
Itś not PNG as your example code, but it will give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea :

- Create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` from your image file/stream.
- Use `LockBits` on the bitmap to access unmanaged image data.
- Call `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy` to copy unmanaged data to your array.
- Call `UnlockBits` on the bitmap to clean up a little.

Do not use `GetPixel` if performance matters as it's slow as hell.